# Wrapping pandoc table column names in r markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, pandoc

I am creating a pandoc.table with long column name that I want to wrap so my table does not go off the pdf page.  I know you can use split.tables, but that takes away the clarity of the table.  Using split.cells doesn't seem to do anything, even when supplied as a vector.

````
---
  output : pdf_document
---

```{r,echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(pander)
mytab = data.frame(ReallySuperExtraLongColumnNameThatIWantToWrap=1:2, col2=2001:2002)
pandoc.table(mytab)
```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will produce a table with a line break in the header:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(pander)
mytab = data.frame("ReallySuperExtraLongColumn\nNameThatIWantToWrap"=1:2,
                  col2=2001:2002,
                  check.names = FALSE)
pandoc.table(mytab)
```
````

The line break is encoded with `\n`. This is not an allowed character in a columnname, and the `data.frame()` function would normally remove it. You can use `check.names = FALSE` to suppress this behaviour and keep the column names exactly as you entered them. Alternatively, you could redefine the column name on a separate line:

```
mytab = data.frame(ReallySuperExtraLongColumnNameThatIWantToWrap=1:2, col2=2001:2002)
names(mytab)[1] = "ReallySuperExtraLongColumn\nNameThatIWantToWrap"
```

You can also set the width of the cells with `split.cells`. The line breaks will then be generated automatically, however, breaks only appear when there is a space in your column header. An example:

````
```{r,echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(pander)
mytab = data.frame("Really Super Extra Long Column Name That I Want To Wrap"=1:2,
                  col2=2001:2002,
                  check.names = FALSE)
pandoc.table(mytab, split.cells = 15)
```
````

This gives breaks after "Extra" and "Name". Note that you still need `check.names = FALSE`, because also spaces are not allowed in data frame names.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I realized that changing the "style" of the pandoc table will actually do what I want as well!  I was using style = 'rmarkdown'; however, style = 'multiline' takes care of it!

Comment: But `style = "multiline"` is the default, so if you don't specify `style`, this will be used. It's true that `style = "rmarkdown"` seems not to support line breaks in cells, but setting `style = "multiline"` allone does not add line breaks where there are no spaces. It will break at spaces and use `split.cells = 30` by default.

Comment: This answer did not work for me. I needed to use the argument `keep.line.breaks` to honor `\n`.